# Is there an example of a custom ResourceProvider for storing RESX files in an external assembly?

Tags: asp.net, resx, localization

We have so, so many RESX files in our ASP.NET 3.5 web application (for localisation purposes) and it's making code changes very slow; every time it runs for the first time all the symbols are built for the re-compiled RESX files.

Ideally I'd like to store these files in an external assembly and create a ResourceProvider that acts as a bridge.

That way the RESX files won't be affected by each subsequent compilation of the web app.

I also don't want to reinvent the wheel; someone must have done this before - but I can't find anything on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it looks like reading through this article is going to be a good bet:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

But I'll still hold out in case someone has an example!!